# Selecting most recent row, per user

Tags: mysql

I have a table with columns `user_id`, `time_stamp` and `activity` which I use for recoding user actions for an audit trail.

Now, I would just like to get the most recent timestamp for each unique `user_id`.  How do I do that?

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question to something less ambiguous like 'a select question'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SELECT MAX(time_stamp), user_id FROM table GROUP BY user_id;`

Answer (score 3):

The following query should be what you want...

```
select user_id,max(time_stamp) from yourtable group by user_id order by user_id, time_stamp desc
```

Comment: This will show **all** duplicate user_id - if user 23 has 45 entries, it will appear 45 times

Comment: Not true, I'm grouping by user_id and the sorting order + max on the time_stamp gives you the most recent time.

The only error  have in my query is the order before group, which I'm correcting after this post.

Comment: in your first version there was no grouping at all

Comment: @Tudor, there was grouping on the original query (you can check in the edit history).

Comment: Oh, you are right - my bad - i took out the downvote and added 1 up

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution and understanding, much appreciated :)